# London highways missing in OSM Data

Tags: openstreetmap, pgrouting, osm2po, geofabrik

I'm working with London OSM data (roads) with PostGIS and pgRouting.

After download the pbf file from Geofabrik and create the topology with osm2po, I've realized that some highways in London are missing (the M25 Highway around Greater London)
I've tried both pbf files: Britain Islands and Great Britain, and in both is missing, but if I search for this highway via Overpass Turbo, I can download it.

¿Has anybody any idea why is this road missing in this dataset? I thought that geofabrik datasets were daily extract from OSM Database.

As a solution, I've thought in manually create the road, and then calculate the topology. ¿Could this be a solution, or would I have to do something more in order to add it to all network?

Comment: Did you import highway=motorway?

Comment: If I import highway=motorway, I get the highway, but the problem comes when I import the whole dataset from geofabrik (http://download.geofabrik.de/europe.html), I get the correct network, but this highway is missing

Comment: Do you get any motorways? - check your osm2po.config file to make sure motorways are being picked up?

Comment: I can't find the way to know it, as osm2po does not show this field. But I've used the same method with other countries before, and I have not find any problem, so I suppose that I do get other motorways.

Comment: Isn't your title misleading because motorways must be there in the data if you can pick them with highway=motorway?

Comment: I don't know if is clear: After download the pbf file, and create topology with osm2po, I can see all roads except one, the M25 highway that encircles london.

Comment: It is available via https://mapzen.com/data/metro-extracts/metro/london_england/ (pbf format)

Comment: One possible reason is dedcribed below the release notes of 5.1.0.